# Why do I have to set Shorten command line for each test method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, intellij-idea

I am new in IntelliJ IDEA and have created some Unit Tests. When trying to run or debug a test method or test class, I get the following error, and then after setting **Shorten command line: @argfile (Java 9+)**, the problem disappears. However, I do not want to make this setting for each testing.

*"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.1\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=2097152 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58467:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\idea_classpath480969239 com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 com.kboxglobal.core.service.impl.unit.BrandMenuItemPriceServiceImplTest,shouldReturnPriceValuesWhenOverrideUuidIsNull
`CommandLineWrapper` is ill-suited for launching apps on Java 9+.
If the run configuration uses "classpath file", please change it to "@argfile".
Otherwise, please contact support.*

There should be a global option for all of the tests in IntelliJ IDEA and if I set it, I will not have to apply the setting above for each testing. But I could not find. How can I set it and fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the dialog to edit the run configuration, on the bottom of the run configuration list there is a link `Edit configuration templates` (see screenshot):

[image: Edit run configuration templates dialog]

In that dialog then select JUnit, click "Modify options" and select `Shorten command line`:

[image: Add shorten command line option]

Then this option will be active for all new JUnit run configurations that you create (note, it will not change existing run configurations for test cases, you have to either edit them manually or delete them and let IntelliJ create them again, when you run those tests).

Comment: Thanks you very much for this detailed answer. It seems to work if I select @argfile (Java 9+) in Shorten command line: option. Is that Ok? Because you did not mention about that option and I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Ah sorry, yes, i forgot that information. `@argfile (Java 9+)` should be correct.